# Why does Tableau Logs [Vertica][ODBC] (11430) Catalog name not supported?

Tags: odbc, tableau-api, vertica

I have been working on Tableau + vertica Solutions.

I have installed relevant vertica ODBC driver from Vertica provided packages .

While going through `tdeserver.txt` log file, I stumbled upon a line of error log as below :

```
{
    "ts": "2015-12-16T21:42:41.568",
    "pid": 51081,
    "tid": "23d247",
    "sev": "warn",
    "req": "-",
    "sess": "-",
    "site": "{759FD0DA-A1AB-4092-AAD3-36DA0923D151}",
    "user": "-",
    "k": "database-error",
    "v": {
        "retcode-desc": "SQL_ERROR",
        "retcode": -1,
        "protocol": "7fc6730d6000",
        "line": 2418,
        "file": "/Volumes/build/builds/tableau-9-2/tableau-9-2.15.1201.0018/modules/connectors/tabmixins/main/db/ODBCProtocolImpl.cpp",
        "error-records": [{
            "error-record": 1,
            "error-desc": "[Vertica][ODBC] (11430) Catalog name not supported.",
            "sql-state": "HYC00",
            "sql-state-desc": "SQLSTATE_API_OPT_FEATURE_NOT_IMPL_ODBC3x",
            "native-error": 11430
        }]
    }
}
```

This piece of log is repeated several times .

Rest of the setup runs smooth as expected .

Below are the attributes from `~/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini`

```
[ODBC]
Trace = 1
TraceAutoStop = 0
TraceFile = ~/log
TraceLibrary =
ThreePartNaming=1
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: What Vertica version are you using and what driver version are you using? See the [Tableau installation guide](https://community.dev.hpe.com/t5/Vertica-Knowledge-Base/HP-Vertica-Integration-with-Tableau-Desktop-Connection-Guide/ta-p/229480) for pointers.

Comment: @Kermit From your pointer, I followed the steps to install ODBC driver ver 7.1.2 , Same as Vertica Server version.
For surety renamed earlier version of ODBC driver as 7.1.1 in ODBC Manager .Still the Error Log persists in the log file .

Comment: I suspect the `ThreePartNaming` property belongs to the corresponding DSN section in `odbc.ini`, not the common section.

Comment: @mustaccio will check and let you know .